# Matrix differentiation proof of quadratic product $x^TAx$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

would appreciate any hints with the proof for $x^TAx$ using index notation:

Suppose $x$ is an $n$ x 1 vector, $A$ is an $n$ x $n$ matrix. $A$ does not depend on $x$, and also $\alpha = x^TAx$.

Let $\alpha = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i a_{ij} x_j$

Differentiating wrt to the $k^{th}$ element of x:

$\frac{\delta\alpha}{\delta x_k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_ia_{ik} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{kj}x_j$ for all $k$ = 1, ... , $n$

$\frac{\delta\alpha}{\delta \boldsymbol{x}} = x^TA + x^TA^T = x^T(A+A^T)$

Now I understand that the $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_ia_{ik}$ component gives us $x^TA$ when we take $\frac{\delta\alpha}{\delta \boldsymbol{x}}$. This is because for each $k$ (which are the columns of $A$) we calculate a sum-product using the vector $x$ and the $k^{th }$ column of $A$. But how does the $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{kj}x_j$ component result in $x^TA^T$ and not $Ax$ in $\frac{\delta\alpha}{\delta \boldsymbol{x}}$ since we are effectively calculating the sum product of $x$ and the $k^{th}$ row of $A$?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is the following: the numbers
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{kj}x_j
$$
are the entries of $Ax$, which is a **column**. On the other hand,
$$
\frac{d\alpha}{dx}=\left(\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x_n}\right)
$$
is a **row**. That is why you need to take the transpose $(Ax)^T=x^TA^T$.

Added: alternatively, note that
$$
\begin{split}
(x+h)^TA(x+h)
&=x^TAx+x^TAh+h^TAx+h^TAh\\
&=x^TAx+(x^TA+x^TA^T)h+h^TAh,
\end{split}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{d}{dh}(x+h)^TA(x+h)|_{h=0}=x^TA+x^TA^T.
$$

Comment: Hello Jonas, thanks for this. I understand your explanation, but do you think there a "cleaner" way to approach this proof? Other than to take the extra step of  column transpose to ensure that our answer is dimension-consistent?

Comment: @clg000 Sure, just added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help Jonas

Answer (score 0):

We see that $$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_j
= [x_1,x_2,...,x_n]\left[\begin{array}{c} a_{k1} \\ a_{k2} \\ ... \\
a_{kn}\end{array}\right]$$
$$=x^T\left[\begin{array}{c} a_{1k}^T \\ a_{2k}^T \\ ... \\
a_{nk}^T \end{array}\right]$$
$$=x^T a_{,k}^T,$$
Where $a_{,k}^T$ is the $k$th column of the matrix $A^T$. This multiplication
holds for each column in $A^T$.

Comment: Hello and thanks Joseph, this makes sense. But $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{kj}x_j = [a_{k1}, ... a_{kn}]\begin{bmatrix}x_1
\\ ...
\\ x_n

\end{bmatrix}$ as well. And this gives us (using your notation) $a_{k,} x$. Is there a reason why you would pick your above approach for calculation instead of this?