# Matrix derivation definition

Tags: matrix-calculus, differential

I am tring to compute a mathematical derivation, but I am obviously missing something.

I precise that I have only learned "formal" definition of derivation in the 1D case, and am not familiar with Banach spaces or this degree of formalism.

I want to calculate $\frac{\partial b^T A b}{\partial b}$ where A is $(k,k)$ and b is $(k,1)$.

This is what I have tried
\begin{align*}
f(b+h)  &= (b+h)^T A (b+h)\\
  &=  b^T A b + h^T A b + b^T A h + h^T A h \\
        &=    f(b) + (b^T A^T h )^T + b^T A h + o(|| h ||) \\
        &=    f(b) + b^T A^T h + b^T A h + o(|| h ||)     \text{ 1D : I take the transpose}         \\
  &=    f(b) + (b^T A^T + b^T A) h + o(|| h||) \\
  &=    f(b) + b^T (A^T + A) h + o(|| h ||) \\
f(b+h)-f(b) &=   b^T (A^T + A) h + o(|| h ||) \\
\end{align*}
I will use an improper (division by $h$), by analogy to the 1D case
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(b+h)-f(b) }{h} &=  b^T (A^T + A) +  o(|| 1 ||) \\
\frac{\partial f(b)}{\partial b} &= b^T (A^T + A)
\end{align*}

But I have found in several courses (for instance [Here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/notes/matrixid.pdf) and [Here](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/courses/fall2009/formulaire.pdf)) that I am supposed to find $(A+A^T)b$.

So I guess my idea is not "too bad" but I am missing a conceptual element (surely linked to my improper derivation ?) because I obtain the wrong dimension.

So

- Can someone correct me ?
- Can someone explain to me the intuition behind why my dimension is not the right one?

Thanks

Comment: Your derivation is fine, as in this reply: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646894/matrix-differentiation-proof-of-quadratic-product-xtax/1646958#1646958

Comment: So is this all a question of how to define $\frac{\partial b^T A b}{\partial b}$ ? (I have added links to lecture notes that give the transpose as the result)

Comment: Right, but the derivative has to be a linear transformation. So, one can say that it is $B=(A+A^T)b$ if we agree that we compute like $h\mapsto B^Th$. Peculiar to write it like that though...

Comment: @Justpassingby isn't it a scalar so that it is legit ?

Comment: @Jonas I am still a bit confused as I do not picture the concept yet. What do you mean by it has to be a linear transformation ? And isn't it strange that most of the references I find (I have linked two) present it the other way

Comment: :) I can't answer for others. How does one define usually the symbol $\frac{\partial b^T A b}{\partial b}$?

Comment: That is kind of my problem. When I search for a proper definition, it is often out of my league. And I do not manage to appropriate it visually. I have the exact same problem with defining $\frac{\partial b^t A}{\partial b}$, (with a (k,1)) is it supposed to be a (1, k) or (k,1) vector ?

Comment: Just added details as an answer, too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's agree that vectors are written as columns.

Since $F(b)=b^TAb$ is a function from $\mathbb R^k$ to $\mathbb R$, the derivative (if it exists) will be a linear transformation $T\colon\mathbb R^k\to L(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R)$ (for each $b\in\mathbb R^k$ the image $T(b)$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^k$ to $\mathbb R$). The map $T$ is defined by requiring that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|F(b+h)-F(b)-T(a)h|}{\|h\|}=0
$$
(and if it exists it is unique).
So, in your case we get $$T(b)h=b^T(A^T+A)h$$ and we usually write simply $$T(b)=b^T(A^T+A),$$but we still should interpret it as a linear transformation. If we write $T(b)=(A^T+A)b$ we would be thinking of the vectors as rows and so we would write $T(b)h=(A^T+A)b\cdot  h$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the case where $b$ is a matrix.

Use the [Frobenius (:) inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to write the scalar-valued function as

$$\eqalign {
 f &= b:Ab \cr
}$$
and take its differential

$$\eqalign {
df &= db:Ab + b:A\,db \cr
   &= Ab:db + A^Tb:db \cr
   &= (A+A^T)\,b:db \cr\cr
}$$
Since $df = \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}:db\Big),\,$ the gradient equals 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= (A+A^T)b \cr\cr
}$$
This result is valid when $b$ is any $(k\times n)$ matrix.
In particular, it is valid when $(n=1)$, i.e. when $b$ is a vector.

Comment: Thank you for your demonstration, but I would also really like to know if you think my "demonstration" is incorrect and then why, and what is the logic behind the dimension we expect of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}$

Comment: Transpose is a useful concept for a 2nd-order tensor, but not for tensors of any other. 
I see students tie themselves up in knots over the use of $v^T$ versus $v$. 
The easiest way around these knots is to reformulate the problem by converting the vectors into matrices (as in the above answer). 
An even better approach to these types of problems is to use tensor/index notation.